# Why is the click event is not fired after .html() ? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, consider this code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#clickme').click(function(){   
      $('#note_pag').html('<div id="note_pag"><ul><li><b>1</b></li><li><a href="2">2</a></li></ul></div>');
   }); 

   $('#note_pag a').click(function(){           
     alert($(this).attr('href'));                  
    return false;
   });
});
</script>


<a href="#" id="clickme">CLICK ME</a>

<div id="note_pag">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="4">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Could someone tell me why I can get the clicks on the links inside `#node_app`, but when I replace the div with `.html()` the event is not fired anymore?

Comment: Wouldn't `$('#someid').html('<div id="someid"></div>')` give you two objects with the same id nested in each other?

Comment: Just a note that .live() as mentioned in many of the answers below is now deprecated. Using .delegate() as _lonesomeday_ mentioned below works nicely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your essentially using `.bind` (via `.click`) the events are only set for the current elements. You're then removing those elements. If you want those events to persist after you've altered the dom, use `.live` instead:

```
$("#note_page a").live("click", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("href"));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) -

```
$('#note_pag a').live('click',function(){           
    alert($(this).attr('href'));                  
    return false;
});
```

also, you should avoid creating a duplicate id when inserting the new content. You could chnage `note_page` to a class instead of an id.

Answer (score 2):

Binding to events via `click()` or `bind()` only works for objects that are already present in the DOM at the time of binding your event handler.

What you are looking for is jQuery's [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function, which allows you to bind handlers to not-yet-existing elements.

Your code would look like this:

```
$('#note_pag a').live('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('href'));                  
    return false;
});
```

**Edit:** To be precise, `live()` binds to `$(document)` and checks the target attribute of events that have bubbled all the way up through the DOM – that's why the binding works even though elements are added after binding the event callback.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="some_triggers">
    <a id="foo" href="#">Foo!</a>
</div>
```

Example jQuery:

```
$('#foo').click(function(){ alert('foo') });
$('#bar').click(function(){ alert('bar') });
$('#some_triggers').append('<a id="bar" href="#">Bar!</a>');
$('#foo').live('click', function(){ alert('foo live()!') });
$('#bar').live('click', function(){ alert('bar live()!') });

// -> clicking #foo alerts "foo" and "foo live()"
// -> clicking #bar alerts "bar live()" only, since the '.click()' binding doesn't work on non-existent DOM elements.
```

**Edit2:**

As mentioned by some of the others (@Marnix, most notably), your "replacement" code is nesting elements with the same ID inside each other every time the click handler executes.

You should replace your

```
 $('#note_pag').html('<div id="note_pag"><ul><li><b>1</b></li><li><a href="2">2</a></li></ul></div>');
```

line with either

```
$('#note_pag').replaceWith('<div id="note_pag"><ul><li><b>1</b></li><li><a href="2">2</a></li></ul></div>');
```

or

```
 $('#note_pag').html('<ul><li><b>1</b></li><li><a href="2">2</a></li></ul>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#note_pag a')
```

This says "find all `a` elements within `#note_pag`".  You then bind an event handler to *those* elements.

```
$('#note_pag').html('<div id="note_pag"><ul><li><b>1</b></li><li><a href="2">2</a></li></ul></div>');
```

When you do this, the elements that the event handlers were bound to above are replaced. (Actually, you're also adding `<div id="note_pag">` every time: you don't need to include the html of the element you're filling.)

Effectively, you need to bind the event handler to a different element, one that always exists. This is possible because ancestor elements are notified of events on descendant elements.  The nicest way to do this with jQuery is the [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) method:

```
$('#note_pag').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));                  
    return false;
});
```

Note that this does the same thing as [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live), but is significantly better optimised in various ways.

Answer (score 1):

event isn't set to the new html after the click

try:

```
$('#note_pag a').live('click', function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$('#note_pag a').click` you would need to use `$('#note_pag a').live("click",handler)`.
Reason : The event was attached to the a node and when you overrite the HTML it becomes a new a node